# Reduce Clique to Set Cover

Tags: set-cover, clique

Is it possible directly to reduce clique to set cover?
I know that there are some ways of direct reduction from Clique to Vertex Cover and from Vertex Cover to Set Cover, so I am very interested to know if the is a way to reduce clique to set cover directly without the use of the transitive rule.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  If you just compose those two reductions that *gives* you a direct reduction.  Have you tried working out what reduction mapping that yields, if you try that?  It seems like that immediately gives you what you want.

Comment: I tried it, but steel can't compouse direct flow, can you please suggest a way how it can be compoused.

Answer (score 1):

Both problems are **NP**-complete and, by definition, there is a direct reduction between any pair of **NP**-complete problems.